# xcode archive error - Attempting to use the forward class— as superclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, app-store

i complate my app.app works fine all emilator device.but I get an error when I try archive for upload appstore.

[image]

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: maybe you should have a look at your compile errors first, before you're going to create an archive in order to upload your app. could you please paste your error code`?

Comment: no errors.aplication works fine.i dont understand.Could the error be in the licenses

Comment: its my first app.

Comment: Have you Found the Solution?